# Rectangle parallel to a radial direction

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, polar

I wanted to draw a rectangle parallel to a radial direction and I achieved this, but I would like to know if there is a *more elegant way* to do it.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border = 0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, shapes, decorations.pathmorphing, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines,step=1.0,green] (-10,-7) grid (7,7); % help grid

\coordinate (A) at (210:6cm);
\draw[fill=black!50!white] (210:6cm) -- ($(A) +(120:1cm)$) -- ($(A)+(120:1cm)+(210:3cm)$) -- ($(A)+(120:1cm)+(210:3cm)+(300:2cm)$) -- ($(A)+(120:1cm)+(210:3cm)+(300:2cm)+(30:3cm)$) -- ($(A)+(120:1cm)+(210:3cm)+(300:2cm)+(30:3cm)+(120:1cm)$) -- cycle;

\draw[cyan] (0:0) -- (210:11cm); % help radial axe
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using six segments to draw a rectangle, so obviously you can shorten it at least, by using only the corners. Another way to make the code shorter is to use relative coordinates, i.e. add `++` before the coordinate.

```
\documentclass[border = 0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, shapes, decorations.pathmorphing, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines,step=1.0,green] (-10,-7) grid (7,7); % help grid

\coordinate (A) at (210:6cm);


\draw[fill=black!50!white] ($(A) +(120:1cm)$) -- ++(210:3cm) -- ++(300:2cm) -- ++(30:3cm) -- cycle;


\draw[cyan] (0:0) -- (210:11cm); % help radial axe
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Another possible improvement is to make all the drawing angles relative to a predefined angle. Below I use `declare function={a=210;}` to make a new constant, and then use e.g. `a+90` in the polar coordinates of the relative coordinates:

```
\documentclass[border = 0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={a=210;}
]

\draw[help lines,step=1.0,green] (-10,-7) grid (7,7); % help grid

\coordinate (A) at (210:6cm);


\draw[fill=black!50!white] ($(A) +(a-90:1cm)$) -- ++(a:3cm) -- ++(a+90:2cm) -- ++(a+180:3cm) -- cycle;


\draw[cyan] (0:0) -- (210:11cm); % help radial axe
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks ! (++) is exactly the trick I was mising and looking for

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You can just rotate the rectangle. In this example, the `around` is not necessary because you rotate around the origin but in general it is. So you just need to put

```
\draw[fill=black!50!white,rotate around={210:(0,0)}] (6,-1) rectangle (9,1);
```

or in this example

```
\draw[fill=black!50!white,rotate=210] (6,-1) rectangle (9,1);
```

to obtain

[image]

```
\documentclass[border = 0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, shapes, decorations.pathmorphing, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines,step=1.0,green] (-10,-7) grid (7,7); % help grid

\coordinate (A) at (210:6cm);
%\draw[fill=black!50!white] (210:6cm) -- ($(A) +(120:1cm)$) -- ($(A)+(120:1cm)+(210:3cm)$) -- ($(A)+(120:1cm)+(210:3cm)+(300:2cm)$) -- ($(A)+(120:1cm)+(210:3cm)+(300:2cm)+(30:3cm)$) -- ($(A)+(120:1cm)+(210:3cm)+(300:2cm)+(30:3cm)+(120:1cm)$) -- cycle;

\draw[fill=black!50!white,rotate around={210:(0,0)}] (6,-1) rectangle (9,1);

\draw[cyan] (0:0) -- (210:11cm); % help radial axe

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution could be a `node` at end of path and `sloped`.

This option `sloped` forces a node to be drawn tangent to the path. 
If you draw a path `(0:0) -- (210:6cm)` that ends where you want the node, option `at end` (or `pos=1`) and correct anchor will asure its position. And `allow upside down` options doesn't change node orientation to keep its contents upside-down, this way the `west` (or `east`) anchor can always be used as reference.

```
\documentclass[border = 0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, shapes, decorations.pathmorphing, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mynode/.style={rectangle, 
        minimum width=3cm, 
        minimum height=2cm, 
        draw=black, 
        fill=black!50, 
        sloped, 
        allow upside down, 
        anchor=west}]

\draw[help lines,step=1.0,green] (-10,-7) grid (7,7); % help grid

\foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}
    \draw[cyan] (0:0) -- (\i:6cm) node[mynode, at end]{}; % help radial axe

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]